# Removing or hiding Computers in network of windows explorer

Tags: network-shares, home-networking

I am trying to hide my computer from being seen in windows explorer. I have tried using net Config sever /hidden but that didn’t work. Another one of my PCs is not on the list and is not hidden with net Config server but can still access the other pc.

Comment: Turn Network Discovery OFF in Advanced Network Properties and see if that changes the overall discovery pattern

Comment: Also, make sure that NetBIOS is disabled.

Comment: Thanks I sort of got it to work I turned of the discovery and it no longer shows up. It didn’t work the first time I tried it.